# Can we add a structure notion on set relations without invoking choice?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, axiom-of-choice

To $\sf ZF$, can we add a primitive one place function symbol $\mathcal S$ [read as *the structure of set relation _*] such that for any binary relations $Q,R$ that are sets, we have: $$1. \ \ \mathcal S (Q)= \mathcal S(R) \iff Q \text{ isomorphic to } R \\ 2. \ \ \mathcal S(Q) 
\text{ isomorphic to } Q$$; without invoking any kind of choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Not even for the empty structure, that is for sets and equipotence. See:

> *Pincus, David*, [**Cardinal representatives**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02760841), Isr. J. Math. 18, 321-344 (1974). [ZBL0302.02021](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0302.02021).