# Is having a canonical representative of set relations equivalent to choice or global choice?

Tags: set-theory, relations, axiom-of-choice

If we add to the language of ZF a one place predicate symbol $\frak Can$, standing for *is Canonical*, then add to axioms of $\sf ZF$ the following axiom:

**Canonicity:** $\forall R: R \text { is a relation } \to \exists! \frak X: Can(X)$$ \land \frak X$$ \, \approx R$

Where $\approx$ signify *isomorphic to*; defined as:

$S \approx R \iff \exists f: dom(S) \cup rng(S) \to dom(R) \cup rng(R) \land f \text{ is bijective } \land \\\forall a,b: \langle a,b \rangle \in S \Leftrightarrow \langle f(a),f(b) \rangle \in R$

; while *is a relation* means being a subset of a cartesian product of two sets.

Now the above is clearly a theorem of $\sf ZF +GC$, but is the opposite true?

That is: is global choice $\sf GC$, or even choice $\sf C$, provable in $\sf ZF + Canonicity$?

Comment: "is isomorphic to" in which category? Sets??

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, we are working in ZF, so everything quantified upon here is a *Set*.

Comment: Your definition for isomorphic switches $R$ and $S$.

Comment: @MarkSaving, yes that was a typo, thanks. Corrected!

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3774727/can-we-add-a-structure-notion-on-set-relations-without-invoking-choice

Comment: @AsafKaragila, yes it is definitely related. But here I'm asking about what grade of choice Canonicity would prove, and in particular if any form of choice equal or stronger to AC is implied by it, I hope that AC won't be proved here and that possibly countable choice or DC at most would be proved.

Comment: These are not easy questions to tackle. If it's not obvious why this implies something, it might very well be because it doesn't. To prove that it doesn't, one needs to modify Pincus' proof about cardinal representatives. In fact, that'd be a good start even for a positive proof, since if it does imply anything, the generalisation of Pincus' theorem won't work. In either case, there's a lot of technical grunt work afoot.